# Search form to find custom meta box generated data

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, custom-field, metabox, search

I have developed an inner theme plugin, which is a custom meta box that inserts some typed in text to the database and then displays in the application.

I followed the example found at [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural). Now the administrator types in some text in the metabox fields (added through jquery) in the wp-admin panel.

Then on update these fields are stored in the database as explained in the shared link above.
The content will then be displayed in the application for users to see.

## Issue:

The search form doesn't find text/keywords from this custom metabox stored data.

**How can I hook up the searchform to find text from these fields?**

Comment: Maybe this plugin, which extends the core WordPress search to include metadata? I haven't used it but it seems to do what you want ... https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-meta-searcher/

Comment: @dougvdotcom thanks I prefer to do it without a plugin. However if no solution is given, i will try it out